# Incognito Lighthouse performance issues

Tags: javascript, vue.js, getstream-io

I am getting this issue while running a performance test.

The suggestions is to run it in incognito, but I am running it in incognito and still getting this issue.

It is still running the test and giving me a score, but it seems something is affecting.

> There were issues affecting this run of Lighthouse:
> There may be stored data affecting loading performance in this location: IndexedDB. Audit this page in an incognito window to prevent those resources from affecting your scores.

Answer (score 1):

i face the very same issue:

[image]

site data showed some amount of data in indexdb although indexdb itself appears empty when i investigate it by clicking the node. after clearing site data indexdb went to 0 ad everything appears cleared. the alert remains unchanged.

when running lighthouse in incognito mode the alert is not there, so that hint at least works fine on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to clear this message by going in to the "Application" tab in Inspector and clicking "Clear site data" and then rerunning the Lighthouse test.

**EDIT:** spoke too soon...  It seemed to clear it the first time and then the 2nd time I tried to re-run the test I got the same warning message.  Perhaps it's not clearing everything?

Comment: The problem persists. Tried it today and the warning is still there.